# Is there a better way to check for null in HttpServletRequest.getParamter()

Tags: java

Can there a better/optimized way to extract value from `request`?

```
void m() {
    String tFlag = request.getParameter("tFlag");

    tFlag = (tFlag == null) ? "" : tFlag;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `String tFlag = request.getParameterMap().getOrDefault("tFlag", "")`?

Comment: I just scanned through the documentation and it just seems intended behavior to return null on no parameter found. What is there to optimize? returning empty string is your own implementation, not HttpServletRequest's.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use Java-8, you can use `Optional.ofNullable` as :

```
String tFlag = Optional.ofNullable(request.getParameter("tFlag")).orElse("");
```

or alternatively the [suggestion from ernest_k in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142968/is-there-a-better-way-to-check-for-null-in-httpservletrequest-getparamter/54143226?noredirect=1#comment95117055_54142968) :

```
String tFlag = request.getParameterMap().getOrDefault("tFlag", "")
```

Comment: using `Optional` for conditional logic is IMO overkill and rather not good practice.

Comment: @Lino true and I do agree with that, just another way of trying things out.